# Orientation change during playing video in Android

Tags: android, video, orientation, exoplayer

I am working on a project in which I have to change the screen orientation to landscape as the video starts in onCreate() method and as soon as the video ends I have to again switch back to the portrait mode using two different layouts for different orientation without recreating the activity. I am using ExoPlayer for video play.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `setRequestedOrientation`-method of your activity:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: I am using this but its not changing the layout which i have designed for landscape mode.